# Table or View For System Views

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

**Problem:**  I'm using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Management Studio and `Intellisense` is working on and off.  It varies by the day, provided that I'm connected to a 2012 server and instance.  When I'm connected to a 2008R2 server and instance, it consistently functions appropriately (absurd).  Aaron Bertrand wrote an [absolutely awesome article here about ways we can troubleshoot this in 2012](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/).  I've gone through the checklist and everything should be done correctly, meaning this probably fits the last item (since it works on and off), though it working fine on 2008R2 seems odd.

**Question:** Instead, I am just going to use scripts to look through objects, but am not finding a script to look at all the system views options, so that I can perform like queries to find if there's anything related.  For instance:

```
sys.assemblies
sys.assembly_files
sys.assembly_modules
sys.assembly_references
sys.assembly_types
```

If I were searching for:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.[TheSourceI'mSeeking]
WHERE name LIKE '%assembl%'
```

This way I could quickly look through the available views that I have (which is where `intellisense` can really help) instead of opening everything.  When I look through `sys.objects`, I don't find system views - is there another way around this?

**Answer (I think this is it):**

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_views
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 1
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the names of system views, or are you also trying to parse the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System views are stored in `sys.all_views`.

If you want to search the code of the views for a specific reference, you can do:

```
SELECT v.name, m.definition
  FROM sys.all_views AS v
  INNER JOIN sys.all_sql_modules AS m
  ON v.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  WHERE v.is_ms_shipped = 1
  AND m.definition LIKE '%assembl%';
```

Of course, this will return every view that references an object named `assembl%` and also every view that has that name. If you want to filter out the latter:

```
  AND v.name NOT LIKE '%assembl%';
```

But I'm not quite sure what your goal is.

Comment: Basically, to return what intellisense would normally return when I type **FROM sys.** (it shows the various choices I have as I begin to look through the views).